# driver to connect to mysql with python

Tags: python, mysql

i am trying to connect to a database and insert data with python.I found too many connector drivers like : mysql-connector,pymysql, MySQLdb. I want to know which way is better to communicate with database in python3.4 .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In our project we have remote machine with MySQL default client, we create SSH object of it and run sql query using traditional client. It's the most safe way and supports mostly everything with best optimized support. 
However, if you want to prepare sql handle in python I will suggest go for pymysql, as pymysql is updated regularly & its very much stable & easy to use compared to others.

Answer (score 0):

I would check out sqlalchemy http://www.sqlalchemy.org/.  Or if you want more of an object-relational-manager then set up a small Django project https://www.djangoproject.com/.